# forEach loop to set property as CSS value

Tags: javascript

so basically what I'm trying to do is create dynamic HTML elements, but there's some weird interaction I'm not understanding.

Here is the code snippet for reference:

`let colorOptions = ["green", "blue", "orange"];`

So what I have is an array that will be dynamically populated but right now it's hard coded.

```js
colorOptions.forEach((item) => {
  colorOption.style.backgroundColor = item;
  optionsArray.push(colorOption);
});
```

And then as you can see I have a forEach loop that sets the backgroundColor of the element to the value of the index.
The problem is that for some reason it  all gets set to the last index.

When I console log item, I get the value of each index. When I console log colorOption I get the value of each index. But some how when it gets pushed to the new array, every index has "orange" assigned as it's background-color.

Here's an [image of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9H53.png)

I feel like I'm missing something stupid, but I'm honestly losing my mind.

Comment: Please edit your question and create a snippet using the toolbar button, so we can run the code and see where it goes wrong. Currently I see undefined variables `colorOption` (singular) and `optionsArray`, and a misconception that `item` is an "index".

Comment: Yeah, what the heck is `colorOption`?  You loop through the colors, but in each iteration of the loop, you're setting the style.backgroundColor of colorOption to the color.  So colorOption.style.backgroundColor will end up as the last item in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
    let colorOptions = ["green", "blue", "orange"];
    let optionsArray = [];

    colorOptions.forEach((item) => {
       let colorOption = document.createElement("div");
       colorOption.innerText = item;
       colorOption.style.backgroundColor = item;
       optionsArray.push(colorOption);    
    });


   optionsArray.forEach((item) => {
      console.log(item);
      document.body.appendChild(item);
   });
```

```js
    let colorOptions = ["green", "blue", "orange"];
        let optionsArray = [];
    
        colorOptions.forEach((item) => {
           let colorOption = document.createElement("div");
           colorOption.innerText = item;
           colorOption.style.backgroundColor = item;
           optionsArray.push(colorOption);    
        });
    
    
       optionsArray.forEach((item) => {
          console.log(item);
          document.body.appendChild(item);
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things happening in your loop.

1. Set colorOption.style.backgroundColor to item
2. Append a *reference* to colorOption to optionsArray

The problem is you are pushing a reference to the same object each time. After the third iteration, you have three references to the same object, which currently has its style.backgroundColor attribute set to "orange". That's why you get three copies of "orange".

I am not totally sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if you really want to use an object in this array, then you need to create a separate object each time you push.

Edit: to prove my point, I believe if you were to `console.log(optionsArray)` instead of `colorOption` as you say, you would see that in the second iteration of your loop, you have two copies of "blue".

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't realize this. It's such a no brainer! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the same div as `colorOption`. If it's the case, the result you got is totally right.

Cause --->

1. In the first iteration the color of the div is getting green.
2. Then in the second iteration, the color of the same div is getting blue.
3. And in the third iteration, it's getting orange.

And since you are pushing the reference of `colorOption`, that means all the divs you've pushed were indicating the same element. So when you are changing the color of that div, all the elements were showing that color.

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes so much sense!